# Is there a weight for html link?

Tags: seo, search-engines, web-crawlers, google-index

I would like to know if there is any weight associated with a html link (its backlink) when google does crawling/indexing. Will 1,2 & 3 be ever considered as a backlink by Google?

```
1. <a href="xyz.com">1</a> // one character link
2. <a href="xyz.com"> </a> //blank space link
3. <a href="xyz.com">!</a> //special character link
4. <a href="xyz.com">keyword</a> //meaningful word link
```

I hope my question is understandable and guess this is right forum. I don't know to put it in other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know links aren't weighted, only their value is measured (partially) depending on the number of keywords in the link. Google also factors in the placement of the link as well.

Comment: So it can be safely assumed any links are links to google. How about links that ain't visible at all? Sorry I am new to this and I couldn't get exact info on this.

Comment: The big G tries to take visibility into account as well. Most blackhat SEO techniques that can be found around the internet won't work, mostly because google checks the websites life cycle as well. So too many links pointing to site appearing "out of nowhere" will be considered as spamming.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. I've written a utility for blogs to add posts and gave it away for free. I've added links back to my couple of my sites with 1 or 2 character links, in order to not distract their users. the utility had gone viral and it'll add almost link every post it creates. Not sure if those links will be considered spammy.

Comment: As long as it points to you pages it'll be considered, but google prefers a steady stream of new links and not a big bang.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. I am just foraying in web development & stuff learning things slowly. Out of curiosity I did the tool and never knew it would backfire :-). Anyway a way to learn. Thanks Galicz.

Comment: I'm hungarian, so Galicz is actually my last name ;)

Comment: Oh I am sorry Miklos :-)

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes 1, 2, and 3 will be counted as a link, because it's a link. Google doesn't look at a social bookmark and give it any lesser value because it's a social bookmark. Just as they don't look at a link on a .edu and give it any more credit based on the TLD.

Google is taking into account hundreds of signals. To Google a link is a link now what else can they determine from the page the link is on? From the pages linking to the page the link is on? From the page the link is linking to?

Their technology page quite a few years ago said they use 100 signals in their algorithm, a few years later it said they use 200 signals. Now it simply says hundreds.

While links play a big roll in determining where you rank there's quite a lot more being considered other than the quantity of characters and words in the anchor alone.

Good links are natural, or look natural and look like someone has put some thought into placing the link.